# Splitting a string into sections based on headers

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I want to split a string into sections based on headers which follow a specific format (`==HEADER==`). Here's what the input string would look like:

```
== Section header ==
Text inside section
=== Maybe a nested section ===
With some more text
And more text
==Then the next section header, perhaps w/o spaces between text and equals signs==
With text inside it
```

Here's the output I'd like:

```
[
    '== Section header ==
    Text inside section
    === Maybe a nested section ===
    With some more text
    And more text',
    '==Then the next section header, without spaces between text and equals signs==
    With text inside it'
]
```

I tried doing

```
pagetext = "== Test header ==\n Some test text, with random equals signs==newlines\n or whatever\n ==Another header    ==   \n more text,\nnewlines\nohmy"
sections = [];
section_re = /==\s*(\s*[^=]*)\s*==/g;
var section_headers = pagetext.match(section_re);
for (var i = 0; i < section_headers.length; i++) {
    var section_start = pagetext.indexOf(section_headers[i]);
    var section_text = pagetext.substring(section_start);
    if (i < section_headers.length - 1) {
        var section_end = section_text.substring(section_headers[i].length).indexOf(section_headers[i + 1]) + section_headers[i].length;
        section_text = section_text.substring(0, section_end);
    }
    sections.push(section_text);
}
```

But it split on the "random equals" signs, giving me:

```
 ["== Test header ==\n Some...ith random equals signs", "==newlines\n or whatever...ore text,\nnewlines\nohmy"]
```

This isn't right. I have a feeling my code may just be too complex -- is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a go with

```
result = subject.match(/^==[^=]*?==$((\r?\n?)(?!==[^=]).*)*/img);
```

Comment: Wow, that looks fabulous! Quick question: will it break on section headers like `== Hello = Goodbye ==` (which are still legitimate headers)?

Comment: ok try 
`result = subject.match(/^==.*?==$((\r?\n?)(?!==[^=]).*)*/img);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling lazy, you can give this a go: https://code.google.com/p/wiki2html/

I've used it successfully before.